# How to save an array into a PHP database

Tags: java, php, android, json

I try to put array in database. In edittext I write for example garlic,tomatoes,onions but when I save data to database and go to my php database, instead of that text it only say ingredients. If I add text manually (i added number manually instead of ingredients but it's the same thing) to database it looks good and create good json file. How can I fix this?

MainActivity.java

```
String id;
    ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();

    @BindView(R.id.etId) EditText etId;
    @BindView(R.id.etIngredients) EditText etIngredients;



    id = etId.getText().toString();
    ingredients = etIngredients.getText().toString();
```

Recipes.java

```
public class Recipes {
    String id;
    List<String> ingredients;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(List<String> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
}
```

And how to retrieve that ingredients in a column?

I use this to return it from json file but it return ingredients in a row [1,3,4,5,6]

```
Reipes rec = recipes.get(position);
    holder.textViewId.setText(rec.getId());
    holder.textViewIngredients.setText(rec.getIngredients().toString());
```

[my online database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDejT.png)

First 4 recipes is added manually, and that where say ingredients is added in android app.

[how it looks when get data in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfnxX.png)

Comment: for a start why are you saving comma-separated values into a single field? This is what one-to-many relationships and foreign keys are for. Start by normalising your database properly. Then if you say the PHP is still not saving it properly, we will need to know exactly the format of data string that you're sending from Java to PHP. If you are happy that string is correct then we need to see the PHP code which is carrying out the save.

Comment: Secondly if you are getting an array of Ingredient IDs back from your PHP server as JSON, and you want to display them in a different way, you have to loop through them and process them individually instead of just dumping the data as a string into your screen (which is what you're doing now).

Comment: You can simply send your ingredients as a string varaiable, why put it as ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace

```
ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
```

by

```
String ingredients;
```

and in your recipies class try to change the type of ingredients

```
String ingredients;
public String getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}
```